# Solution of the equation of motion for a free particle with time-varying mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, differential-equations

I cannot understand which kind of solution has this differential equation representing a free particle with time-varying mass:

$\ddot x + \frac{\dot m(t)}{m(t)}\dot x=0$

I would like to find the propagator of a particle with time-variable mass using this paper as a reference (http://dx.doi.org/10.2306/scienceasia1513-1874.2006.32.173)  but I am stuck on the equations of motion.
Apologies in advance if the question is silly and thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot understand which kind of solution has this differential equation representing a free particle with time-varying mass:
>
> $\ddot x + \frac{\dot m(t)}{m(t)}\dot x=0$

Multiply both sides by $m$ to see that this is equivalent to
$$
m\ddot x + \dot m \dot x = 0
$$
$$
=\frac{d}{dt}\left(m\dot x\right) = 0 \;.
$$

In other words, the particle momentum
$$
p = m \dot x\;.
$$
is constant/conserved:
$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = 0\;.
$$
This occurs when there is no net force on the particle.

---

> I would like to find the propagator of a particle with time-variable mass using this paper as a reference (http://www.scienceasia.org/2006.32.n2/v32_173_179.pdf)  but I am stuck on the equations of motion.

The linked paper appears to explicitly work out exactly the propagator you are interested in. Unless you put some more context and clarity into the phrase "stuck on the equations of motion," I think there is little further help I can provide.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would exactly like to follow the path proposed in the paper but for a free particle with time dependent mass, while in the paper the harmonic oscillator is considered.
In the paper they start with the Euler-Lagrange equations in order to derive the equation of motion which obviously for physical reasons has a solution of the type: $x(t)=\rho(t)(A\cos\gamma(t)+B\sin\gamma(t))$ for a free particle what general solution of the equation of motion should I use? I really apologise if the question is too silly, I've been looking at it all day and I'm getting confused.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what happens when $\omega(t) \to 0$?